# Python Export Excel Sheet Range as Image

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, win32com

So it seems there's something weird going on with PIL ImageGrab.grabclipboard()

```
import win32com.client
from PIL import ImageGrab

o = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
o.visible = False

wb = o.Workbooks.Open(path)
ws = wb.Worksheets['Global Dash']

ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(66,16)).CopyPicture()  
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
imgFile = os.path.join(path_to_img,'test.jpg')
img.save(imgFile)
```

When I run this, I notice that if I ctrl-V , the image is actually correctly saved on the clipboard, but my img variable returns None, meaning ImageGrab.grabclipboard() is somehow not working. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like `PIL` doesn't support the format of the image attached to the clipboard. Try to set a different format: `.CopyPicture(Format:=xlBitmap)` or extract the clipboard with another library.

Comment: got invalid syntax with your arguments, and removing the colon gives me a NameError: 'xlBitmap' is not defined

Comment: The example from my comment is for VBA. You need to convert it to python by providing the missing arguments and constants (`xlBitmap = 2`).

Comment: Right, should have recognized that from the `:= `, thanks! However, still having the same issue as before, while the image is clearly in my clipboard because i can manually paste it, i can't get `ImageGrab.grabclipboard()`
 to grab anything

Answer (score 8):

Here I have a solution which might help you.

```
import excel2img
excel2img.export_img("example.xlsx/example.csv","image.png/image.bmp","sheet!B2:H22")
```

This is working perfectly for me.

Comment: That's gonna be so useful to me! Thanks

Comment: This dont support for microsoft excel 2016. any alternatives ?

Comment: @PythonBang did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me.
Try to start Excel with:

```
o = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
```

Then use win32com.client.constants to get the xlBitmap

```
wb = o.Workbooks.Open(workbook_file_name)
ws = wb.Worksheets("Vs. Disk or Retrofit Chart View")
ws.Range(ws.Cells(22,1),ws.Cells(62,8)).CopyPicture(Format= win32com.client.constants.xlBitmap)  
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
imgFile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'test.jpg')
img.save(imgFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify those comments of Florent B. and David Yang

Add optional parameter `Format` into `.CopyPicture()` will make `ImageGrab.getclipboard()` work as expected.

The following code will be
`ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(66,16)).CopyPicture(Format = 2)`

Number `2` is xlBitmap, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copypicture

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(66,16)).CopyPicture()` by `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(66,16)).Copy()` and it
worked perfectly.

So this is the entire code.

```
import win32com.client
from PIL import ImageGrab

o = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
o.visible = False

wb = o.Workbooks.Open(path)
ws = wb.Worksheets['Global Dash']

ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(66,16)).Copy()  
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
imgFile = os.path.join(path_to_img,'test.jpg')
img.save(imgFile)
```

Comment: Got it [Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman), I'll avoid such phrases
 in my future contributions.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the method posted in the comments under the question and it actually works!
Pay attention to use `win32com.client.constants` to get the `xlBitmap`.
In addition, my environment is `Python 3.6` and I haven't tried it again in `Python 2.7`.

```
win32c = win32com.client.constants
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(66,16)).CopyPicture(Format= win32c.xlBitmap)

img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
imgFile = os.path.join(path_to_img,'test.jpg')
img.save(imgFile)
```

Comment: I am getting a AttributeError: xlBitmap error when adding the format = win32c.sxlbitmap

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is:

```
import win32com.client
from PIL import ImageGrab

wb_file_name = 'Input.xlsx'
outputPNGImage = 'Output.png'

xls_file = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")

wb = xls_file.Workbooks.Open(Filename=wb_file_name)
xls_file.DisplayAlerts = False 
ws = wb.Worksheets("Desired_Tab")
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(15,3)).CopyPicture(Format= win32com.client.constants.xlBitmap)  # example from cell (1,1) to cell (15,3)
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
img.save(outputPNGImage)
wb.Close(SaveChanges=False, Filename=wb_file_name)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).