# python AttributeError when attempting to save excel chart using PIL

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-3.6

I am trying to save an chart from `excel` into a file, which I want to use later in a `powerpoint` presentation, but the code I am running keeps on coming up with

> "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'" .

Have been looking around google/stackoverflow but none of the suggestions I can find actually help, I keep on getting the error.

The code I am trying is below,

```
import win32com.client
import PIL

folder_path = r'C:/temp/Monthly_Graphs.xlsm'

xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folder_path)
xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folder_path)

wb.Sheets('Sheet1').Shapes('Sheet1_Pie_Chart').CopyPicture()    
pie_image = PIL.ImageGrab.grabclipboard()

pie_image.savefig(r'C:/temp/pie_test.bmp','BMP')
```

the traceback is below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-b8e52c17e4d1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/python/stackoverflow_1.py', wdir='C:/python')

  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py64bit\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py64bit\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/python/stackoverflow_1.py", line 26, in <module>
    pie_image.savefig(r'C:/temp/pie_test.bmp','BMP')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

Comment: Show the full error with trace. You aren't calling `save` here anywhere, so you must be passing bad data somewhere.

Comment: added the traceback into the question.  also updated the script to show the dispatch command.

Comment: The error in the trace is different from the error at the top of the question. Please make sure you post the errors correctly. The error in the trace means that `grabclipboard()` is returning `None`. Read the documentation for that method to see what that means.

Comment: thanks,  the issue is with the line  : 
 wb.Sheets('Sheet1').Shapes('Sheet1_Pie_Chart').CopyPicture().     For some reason it doesn't copy the image into the clipboard.  If i open the excelfile and manually select and copy the picture, then use the imagegrab lines directly in the console the image comes out.   Trying to work through the Excel API documentation but not with much luck.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work by referring to the below Q and setting the format of the CopyPicture line.   Issue seems to be that excel default copy of the image is not in a format that PIL understands

[Python Export Excel Sheet Range as Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850522/python-export-excel-sheet-range-as-image?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
    import win32com.client
    from PIL import ImageGrab
    import win32clipboard as clip

    folder_path = r'C:/temp/Monthly_Graphs.xlsm'

    xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folder_path)
    xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folder_path)

    wb.Sheets('Sheet1').Shapes('Sheet1_Pie_Chart').CopyPicture(Format=clip.CF_BITMAP)

    pie_image = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()

    pie_image.save(r'C:/temp/pie_test.bmp','BMP')
```