# How to save Excel Range as vector graphics file using win32com

Tags: excel, python-imaging-library, win32com

***TL;DR***

This is incorrect:

```
# Vector Graphics
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(7,5)).CopyPicture(Format = 1).Export('test.wmf')
```

What is the correct way to export that picture to a `.wmf` file using `win32com`?

***Full Version***

I've been trying to save a range of cells that I have in a xlsx file as a good looking image using Python.

I prefer **PNG** to **JPEG** because of how the appearance of the horizontal and vertical rules differs between the two.

My top preference would be **SVG**, but I haven't been able to find that as an option.

Right now, I have been using this approach (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44850522/6394617) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065420/6394617)):

```
import win32com.client
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image

o = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
o.visible = False

wb = o.Workbooks.Open(path + fname)
ws = wb.Worksheets['Sheet1']

# copy and save as image
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(7,5)).CopyPicture(Format = 2)
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()

# to increase resolution
factor = 4 
length_x, width_y = img.size
size = int(factor * length_x), int(factor * width_y)
img_resize = img.resize(size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

# save as png
imgFile = os.path.join(img_path,'test.png')
img.save(imgFile, 'PNG', compress_level=0, dpi=(500, 500))
```

However, it doesn't look good, and increasing `factor` or the **DPI** doesn't seem to be making it look good.  I think the problem is the DPI that `CopyPicture(Format = 2)` uses, but I cannot find a way to adjust that in any way that is making a difference.

I've read that `PIL` can read **EMF** and **WMF** files, so I was thinking that I could save the `CopyPicture(Format = 1)` to a file, read it in PIL with a very high DPI, then save it as a PNG.

```
# Vector Graphics
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(7,5)).CopyPicture(Format = 1).Export('test.wmf')

with Image.open("test.wmf") as im:
    im.load(dpi=500)
```

However, my code is throwing an error:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'Export'
```

...no doubt due to my ignorance of how to use win32com for MS Excel.

Comment: Is there any fancy formatting involved, or could you read the values in Python and create an image from them?

Comment: I have it formatted the way it is supposed to look in a certain report.  My work prefers to use MS Excel and MS Word.  I will eventually be putting the pictures (of different ranges) into the word file.

Comment: Have you tried specifying 1 or 2 for the [first argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copypicture#syntax) of `CopyPicture`? It does not return a picture object either.

Comment: @GSerg, I tried using `CopyPicture(2,2)` and `CopyPicture(Appearance=2, Format=2)`, but was getting an error:  `com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'CopyPicture method of Range class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)`, which I wasn't able to find information about online, so I gave up on trying to use `Appearance` and started trying to find other approaches.

Comment: @Joe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740062/copypicture-method-of-range-class-failed-sometimes#comment66602480_24740062?

Comment: @GSerg, I looked through that post, but a solution doesn't seem apparent to me.  I don't do any VBA programming, just Python, so I really have no idea how to adapt that code to my problem.  A lot of the SO posts that I have looked through do seem focused on charts, whereas I just want to export my range of formatted cells to a picture with high resolution (or better yet, SVG).

Comment: @Joe VBA is just another client calling the Excel COM API which actually does the job. If the solution for VBA is to call it several times, or make sure there is a pause between certain two invocations, it will apply to any caller of the API, be it VBA or win32com.